# How do I solve Error org.json.jsonexception.No value fo login

Tags: android

I'm trying to login a registered user using their email and password from the registration `credentials`. How do I place value for `login`?

This is for a new  `xamp server`.  ,

```
private void Login( final String email, final String password) {

    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String result) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                        if (success.equals("1")){

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ){

                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                                String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                                        "Success login. \nYour Name : "
                                                +name+"\nYour Email : "
                                                +email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error " +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            })
    }
```

Comment: share your json please.

Comment: share your json file too.., error might be because of no jsonArray with name "login" and also post your log

Comment: it says that you are looking for `login` where it is not. Check or better show your JSON.

Comment: if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
             $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
             if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
              $response["error"] = FALSE;
              $response["user"]["name"] = $row["name"]; 
              $response["user"]["email"] = $row["email"]; 
              echo json_encode($response);
             } else{
              $response["error"] = TRUE;
              $response["error_msg"]= "Wrong credentials"; 
              echo json_encode($response); 
             }
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
?>